# Implementing RTL on a slider plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

After [several](https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/issues/896) [requests](https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/issues/818) [ignored](https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/issues/751) by the developer to support RTL, I'm trying to do it myself.

Reversing the array order was pretty straightforward:

```
self.items = !!(_options.rtl) ? _items = items.reverse() : _items = items; // Reverse the array for RTL
```

.. however the other challenge is swiping RTL. So swiping right from slide 4 (which is the first slide) should slide to the next slide (Slide 3).

[image]

All the magic happens in this function I believe, but I can't quite figure what to tweak:

```
_moveMainScroll = function(x, dragging) {

    if(!_options.loop && dragging) {

        if (_options.rtl) {
            console.log('RTL enabled');
            console.log('_currentItemIndex: ', _currentItemIndex);
            console.log('_slideSize.x: ', _slideSize.x);
            console.log('_currPositionIndex: ', _currPositionIndex);
            console.log('x: ', x);
            var newSlideIndexOffset = _currentItemIndex + (_slideSize.x * _currPositionIndex - x) / _slideSize.x,
                delta = Math.round(x - _mainScrollPos.x);
            console.log(newSlideIndexOffset, delta);
        }
        else {
            var newSlideIndexOffset = _currentItemIndex + (_slideSize.x * _currPositionIndex - x) / _slideSize.x,
            delta = Math.round(x - _mainScrollPos.x);
            console.log(newSlideIndexOffset, delta);
        }

        if( (newSlideIndexOffset < 0 && delta > 0) || (newSlideIndexOffset >= _getNumItems() - 1 && delta < 0) ) {
                x = _mainScrollPos.x + delta * _options.mainScrollEndFriction;
        } 
    }

    _mainScrollPos.x = x;
    _setTranslateX(x, _containerStyle);
}
```

Here's what my code so far: https://jsfiddle.net/tdx3p1p3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use [PhotoSwipe](http://photoswipe.com/) the regular way, in particular passing your `items` array as usual (i.e. first slide at index `0`), but have the gallery place this slide `0` at the "right-most" position, then slide `1` on its left, etc. and have the top left counter show the slide "index" (offset by 1 to avoid displaying "0") accordingly (therefore just using `options.index: 3` is not enough).

If this is correct, you would like the 2<sup>nd</sup> layout imagined by @e_i_pi:

```
                            ********
 Slide4 < Slide3 < Slide2 < *Slide1*
                            ********
```

Therefore you need 3 things:

1. Reverse your `items` array.
2. Start at the right-most slide.
3. Modify the UI counter so that the reported slide index is "reversed".

You do not need to do these 3 operations by tweaking the code within PhotoSwipe script. You could just use a "wrapper" function that performs those operations, and still use the PhotoSwipe code unmodified (so that it is much easier for you to upgrade later on, and benefit from future improvements in the library).

**1. Reverse your `items` array:**

As you figured out, that is the simplest operation: `items = items.reverse()`

**2. Start at the right-most slide:**

As proposed by @e_i_pi, you just need to pass an `index` [option](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/options.html) that is equal to the *new* index (i.e. after reversal) of your "first" slide: `index = items.length - 1`

It was initially at index `0`, and after reversal it is now the "last" item.

**3. Reverse the UI counter:**

That is slightly more advanced, but nothing too complicated.

As [shown](https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/issues/819#issuecomment-94652574) by PhotoSwipe's author, it is easy to customize the UI counter, but the gallery requires to be initialized first. Therefore, the "wrapper" function needs to initialize the gallery internally.

Then logic to build the new UI counter content is not too complex. You just need to take the total number of items and subtract the current index in the `items` JS array:

```
                            ********
 Slide4 < Slide3 < Slide2 < *Slide1*
                            ********
    0        1       2         3     <= index in items JS array
    4        3       2         1     <= "index" to be shown in UI counter
```

So you could have something like:

```js
var total = gallery.options.getNumItemsFn();
var current = gallery.getCurrentIndex();
var reversed = total - current;
var separator = gallery.options.indexIndicatorSep;
indexIndicatorDOMElement.innerHTML = reversed + separator + total;
```

Put everything together, and you have a wrapper function that you can put in its own JS file, so that you can use it anywhere you wish.

```js
// Wrapper initialize function that does the RTL conversion automatically.
// Note: it will also automatically initialize the PhotoSwipe, because it needs to be initialized for UI counter to be modified.
function photoSwipeRTL(pswpElement, uiClass, items, options) {
  // 1. Reverse the items.
  items = items.reverse();

  // 2. Override the start index.
  var itemsIndexMax = items.length - 1;
  var index = options.index || 0; // If not provided, use 0.
  // Now reverse the start index.
  options.index = itemsIndexMax - index;

  // Now instantiate a PhotoSwipe and initialize it, so that we can modify its UI counter.
  var pswp = new PhotoSwipe(pswpElement, uiClass, items, options);
  pswp.init();

  // Get the counter element provided in options, or get it from DOM.
  var indexIndicatorDOMElement = options.indexIndicatorDOMElement || document.querySelectorAll('.pswp__counter')[0];

  // 3. Modify the UI counter.
  pswp.ui.updateIndexIndicator = function() {
    // This code reverses the current index compared to the total number of items in the gallery.
    var total = pswp.options.getNumItemsFn();
    var current = pswp.getCurrentIndex();
    var reversed = total - current;
    var separator = pswp.options.indexIndicatorSep;
    indexIndicatorDOMElement.innerHTML = reversed + separator + total;
  };
  // force index update
  pswp.ui.updateIndexIndicator();

  return pswp;
}
```

And you can use it very simply, almost like the standard PhotoSwipe, except that you just execute the factory (no need for `new` keyword), and no need to initialize the gallery, because it is already done internally.

```
// INITIALIZE
var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];

// build items array
var items = [slide1, slide2, slide3, slide4];

// define options (if needed)
var options = {
  indexIndicatorSep: ' of ',
  indexIndicatorDOMElement: document.querySelectorAll('.pswp__counter')[0]
};

// Initializes and opens PhotoSwipe
var gallery = photoSwipeRTL(pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
```

Live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/kPeFeZbwhqHzbz8A9VRK?p=preview

Comment: Wow, thats a brilliant solution! Thanks heaps!

Comment: The only issue I noticed so far is that `history` feature doesn't seem to work well with it and might need tweaking as well.

Answer (score 2):

Never used that library before, so I might be a bit naive here. Your `rtl` option seems to only reverse the order of the elements, and have no effect otherwise. Looking at the code, I can't see that this will be a problem, but I didn't look into the caption issue that the developer mentioned in that article you linked to.

---

Forgive me if I'm wrong, but I *think* this is what you're after:

```
                            ********
 Slide1 < Slide2 < Slide3 < *Slide4*
                            ********
```

If this is the case, you want the order the same, but the initial element to be Slide 4 (i.e. index 3):

```
var options = {
    ...
    rtl: false,
    index: 3
};
```

If this is the case, then I don't think you even need to  `_options.rtl` variable.

---

If, on the other hand, you want this layout:

```
                            ********
 Slide4 < Slide3 < Slide2 < *Slide1*
                            ********
```

...then you can use this configuration:

```
var options = {
    ...
    rtl: true,
    index: 3
};
```

...which will of course necessitate the `_options.rtl` variable, and may require testing around captions.